# Routine to zip multiple files in-memory produces corrupt zip files

Tags: .net, zip

The following routine is from a file service class in a Web API. The intent of the routine is to receive a list of file paths and return the zip file as a byte array. (The routine that calls this one will handle delivering the file to the user.) This routine makes use of the `ZipArchive` class from `System.IO.Compression`.

The files that this routine produces are corrupt. The return value is always 1024 bytes in size.

This code is almost identical to examples that I found on MSDN and Stack Overflow. What is incorrect about it?

```
public byte[] RetrieveMultipleFilesAsZip(IEnumerable<string> relativePaths)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var path in relativePaths)
            {
                try
                {
                    // ActualPath(): Get the actual path where the file actually lives.
                    var actualPath = ActualPath(path);
                    var filename = Path.GetFileName(actualPath);
                    if (filename == null) continue;

                    var archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(filename);
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(archiveEntry.Open()))
                    {
                        // RetrieveFile(): A routine in this class that gets the contents of each file.
                        writer.Write(RetrieveFile(path));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // ignore this
                }
            }

        }

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return memoryStream.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tracing through the code, it appears that only the entry for the file is getting written to the stream, not the contents of the file. Given 6 files of various sizes, only about 350 bytes were written within the `using archive` block. On exiting the `using archive` block, another 400 bytes were written.

Answer (score 0):

Change `StreamWriter` to `BinaryWriter`, and set the `compressionLevel` parameter of `archive.CreateEntry()`.

Comment: Now I get a Zip file that is properly sized, but Windows says is invalid. Since this routine is supposed to return the file as `byte[]` to the caller, it is possible that the routine that sends this file to the user is messing it up.

Comment: Appears that one of my test files was corrupt, or caused the archive to become corrupt.